# angularjs date filter ignores apostrophe

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I would like to have date formatted like here on SO: "Feb 6, '14".

I cannot put the apostrophe there before the number 14.

I tried the following formatter strings:

```
{{model.since | date:'MMM&nbsp;d,&nbsp;\'yy'}}
{{model.since | date:'MMM&nbsp;d,&nbsp;&#39;yy'}}
{{model.since | date:"MMM&nbsp;d,&nbsp;'yy"}}
{{model.since | date:"MMM&nbsp;d,&nbsp;&#39;yy"}}
```

The apostrophe is not displayed.

How can I put the apostrophe there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation on [date](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate):

**In order to output single quote, use two single quotes in a sequence (e.g. "h 'o''clock'").**

Since a string literal must also be enclosed in single quotes, you need **four** single quotes in a row. And since you're using single quotes in your format, you need to enclose the entire format string with double quotes, rather than single quotes.

Thus, your formatter string should be `{{model.since | date:"MMM&nbsp;d,&nbsp;''''yy"}}`